# Error: Duplicate platform Windows-x86 found for extension com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air

Trying to compile a AIRKinect project in Flash and keep getting the following error

'The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Duplicate platform Windows-x86 found for extension com.as3nui.nativeExtensions.air.kinect

Can anyone suggest some troubleshooting steps?
I have been able to compile without errors in the past, this is the first time I have seen this.

Answer (score 3):

ok , this is what I did to resolve

deleted contents of my Temp folder(not everything could be deleted because some files were in use)

here

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp

Rebooted Flash and compiled

Comment: thanks for this , i was getting the error because firs i tried with the mssdk ane and then changed to openni , this totally solved the problem